How do I turn off notifications for reactions to my messages in Discord?
Recently, while using Discord, I've been receiving notifications about reactions to my messages. In particular, push notifications on mobile are especially annoying.
While I appreciate notifications about @mentions or replies to my messages, I do not care at all what reactions people attach to my messages.
How can I turn these notifications off?

Discord recently implemented this feature, which is at the time of writing marked as experimental.
To turn off notifications for reactions on the desktop application or the web browser, you should go into your user settings using the cog wheel in the lower-left portion of the application, navigate to the "Notifications" list option, and under "Reaction Notifications", set the option to "Never". You can alternatively use the search box in the top-left portion of the page to search for "Reaction notifications" and adjust the option there.
Here is a screenshot of the page, with the relevant sections circled:

On mobile, you need to access the settings menu in Discord by tapping on your profile icon and tapping the cog wheel in the top-right portion of your profile page, then scroll to the Notification settings. You can alternatively access this menu by clicking on the "Notifications" bell icon at the bottom of the app when viewing your list of servers, then click the ellipses in the top-right and choose "Notification settings".
Once there, there is an option toward that's the same as the Desktop version: "Reaction notifications", which can be changed to "Never". You can also adjust these notifications by tapping the "Get notifications outside of Discord" option, which will take you to your app's settings via your device's OS. From there, at least on Android, under "Notifications" is a section for "Social" notifications, under which "Reactions" is able to be turned off.
